Setting Query Parameters for External Call activity in Azure Data Factory
I'm trying to query the open source Yahoo Finance API using Azure Data Factory.
I have a dataset, which is set up like this:

I am calling this API in a data flow. The second line of the data flow using the dataset above works. It is set up like this:


And my flatten activity returns data as below:

However, I want the period1 and period2 query parameters to be dynamic. I have a dataset with historical data and I want to get from between the latest date in the historical data and now. This is where the first line in my data flow comes in and this does not work.
I have found the second line in the data flow can only process about 5 days at a time so I've ingested the historical data and calculated the start and end timestamps using the first 3 activities in the data flow. The UNIX start timestamp is calculated as:
toString(toLong(addDays(MAX_DATE, 1) - toTimestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')) / 1000l)
The UNIX end timestamp is calculated as:
toString(toLong(addDays(MAX_DATE, 6) - toTimestamp('1970-01-01 00:00:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')) / 1000l)
And I get this result:

(P.S. I'm not sure why the timestamps are displayed in that format with an E? Is that an issue?)
From here, I'm trying to use the External Call activity to pass the startTimestamp and endTimestamp as query parameters but I'm falling down at the first hurdle:

I'm not sure why the connection is failing despite using the same set up as the working dataset and I'm not sure why I'm getting a Column not found error despite using the same set up as in the second line of the data flow.  When I try to preview the data, I get the below error:

Spark job failed: {
"text/plain": "{"runId":"a8c1da6c-241b-4b90-891d-3d9bba2ec317","sessionId":"b66a1630-0795-4214-894a-2f333d98b891","status":"Failed","payload":{"statusCode":400,"shortMessage":"DF-EXPR-010 at Call 'ImportYahooFinanceData'(Line 31/Col 24): Column 'interval' used in expression is unavailable or invalid.","detailedMessage":"Failure 2024-11-04 13:04:28.500 failed DebugManager.processJob, run=a8c1da6c-241b-4b90-891d-3d9bba2ec317, errorMessage=DF-EXPR-010 at Call 'ImportYahooFinanceData'(Line 31/Col 24): Column 'interval' used in expression is unavailable or invalid."}}\n"
} - RunId: a8c1da6c-241b-4b90-891d-3d9bba2ec317

Any help with this error is appreciated!
And once this error is solved, how can I pass my start and end timestamps to the External Call activity as query parameters?
Thanks!

where you are facing error


I'm not sure why the timestamps are displayed in that format with an E? Is that an issue?

The displayed value is scientific value for that number to convert it into proper format you can use todecimal() function in derived column as follow:

Output:


Column 'interval' used in expression is unavailable or invalid.

The above error you are getting because you are either referencing column which is not present, or column name is incorrect. query parameter can be used to pass query string parameters in the URL for a REST API call.
Example URL with Query Parameters:
https://api.example.com/data?param1=value_from_pipeline_param&param2=value2

Check the URL you are using is correct or in proper format and check if it is working on browser or postmen
